# Views getting placed at center in android studio 2.2.2

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android studio 2.2.2, while creating layouts in xml, the views get placed at center even without setting them.

**xml:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_goals"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/titlebar_text"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**toolbar xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: show your `tool_bar` layout

Comment: added toolbar xml

Comment: Why do you want a parent RelativeLayout? Nothing in your layout needs to be relative to one another... How about you set the Toolbar to anchor at the top?

Comment: It is not happening to this particular layout but to all other layouts as well, I have posted one of the layouts for example